# Question on Green formula : It work enven if the domain is not compact?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $d\geq 2$ and let $f\in \mathcal C_c^2(\mathbb R^d)$. Show that $$f(x)=-\int_{\mathbb R^d} G(x,y)\Delta f(y)dy=f(x)$$
for all $x\in \mathbb R$ where $G(x,y)$ is the fundamental solution of Laplace equation (but it's not important for the question).

Let $x\in \mathbb R^d$. Then for all $\varepsilon>0$, by Green formula
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d\backslash B(x,\varepsilon)}G(x,y)\Delta f(x,y)dx=\int_{\mathbb R^d\backslash B(x,\varepsilon)}\Delta _y G(x,y)f(y)dy+\int_{\partial B(x,\varepsilon)}[G(x,y)\partial _\nu f(y)-\partial G_\nu(x,y) f(y)]dy,$$
where $\nu$ is the normal vector of $\partial B(x,\varepsilon)$.

I thought that Green formula (or in fact divergence theorem) could be used only on compact set as written here : [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem). So why can we use it here ? It's a mistakes ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Your function $f$ is compactly supported.